# How to start multiple py files (2 discord bots) from one file at once

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm wondering how would I run my 2 discord bots at once from main, app.py, file.

And after I kill that process (main file process), they both would stop.

Tried os.system, didn't work. Tried multiple subprocess.Popen, didn't work.
Am I doing something wrong?

How would I do that?

Comment: Either make two separate classes for each bot in the app.py and run it in the mainloop or have 3 files with 2 of them being bots and the third app.py to which you import the bots and run them parralely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` in python. [Link for docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) Example:

**bot1.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready bot1")

@client.command()
async def command1(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bot1")

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**bot2.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready bot2")

@client.command()
async def command2(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bot2")

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**main.py**

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('python bot1.py')
subprocess.Popen('python bot2.py')
```

In command line: `python main.py` and wait when 2 bots will be ready.

Result:

[image: Result]

P.S. You will have one problem: one bot will issue errors if it doesn't see the commands you run for another bot. It's big problem for debugging. Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: thank you for your answer, bot those 2 bot files are in another folder, each in its own folder

Comment: you can use `python path_to_your_bot_file` instead of `python bot1`

Answer (score 0):

I think the good design is to have one bot per .py file. If they both need code that is in app.py then they should 'import' the common code. Doing that you can just run both bot1.py and bot2.py.

Comment: There are 3 files. 2 for bots, and 1 main file

Comment: Ok but I think you should not run the bots from the main file. Just start both bot separately.

Comment: I understand that, but I can run only one file in VSC, plus the main file contains flask stuff like API ...

Comment: You can try to use Multi Target debugging (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging) to run your 2 bots at the same time in VScode.

Comment: okay, what's debugging supposed to do? Can I edit files in the meantime?

Comment: You will be able to run both bots following this guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging. I you just need to create a configuration with "program":"${workspaceFolder}/bots1.py and another with "program":"${workspaceFolder}/bots2.py . I don't think you will be able to edit files when its running.

Comment: Is there still an alternative?

Comment: Maybe but I don't know other ways to resolve your problem.